# process is not defined error using @wordpress/scripts package

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, process

I am using `@wordpress/scripts` package within my **Wordpress** website to implement a **React** based plugin.
I am trying to access the *environment variables* that I need using `process.env` reference, but it gives me the described error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined**"

How can I access the process object if someone has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to access my environment variables, but I am getting that the process is undefined.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.